# Not able to create new flutter project in Android Studio

Tags: flutter

Not able to create a new flutter project in Android Studio, the related setting is added properly but still, the project is not getting created.

Added the flutter SDK in the path (C:\src\flutter\flutter) and dart plugin is also added to Android studio.

I have created the new project like this File -> New -> New Flutter Project -> Flutter Application, then Android studio opens a pop up "***creating new project***" and getting stuck there for more than 1hr but a new project is not created.

Comment: Are you able to create a project from the command line? `flutter create project1`

Comment: please follow this steps   like File -> New -> New Flutter Project -> Flutter Application

Comment: @RichardHeap I tired by cmd line , but it is falling to create the new project in android studio. Giving me error of required new  android sdk.

Comment: @JaimilPatel  I followed the same way not working

Comment: Please reffer this document https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor

Answer (score 0):

There was previously filed [issue ticket](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16659) related to this issue. If you'll try to check [this thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16659#issuecomment-566479372), these 3 things could be the culprit:

> There are 3 things that you have to check:
>
> 1. Make sure that the flutter SDK isn't in a location that requires some kind of privileges from admin.
> 2. Make sure the Flutter SDK is in a folder that doesn't contain any spacing in names. For ex. C://src/flutter is right and C://sr
>    c/flutter is wrong.
> 3. Android Studio must have a path of Flutter and Dart SDK. For that go to Setting--> Languages and Framework-->Dart/Flutter